# To build, or not to build a kind of Gridview control from scrach?

Tags: asp.net

I want to show some results in a GridView kind of way.
But for each page I want to show 3 "inner Repeaters" showing data from 1-10,11 20 and 21-30 respectively. You can see this in the folowing image.

[alt text http://img196.imageshack.us/img196/1285/examplesv.jpg](http://img196.imageshack.us/img196/1285/examplesv.jpg)

My question is, is this easier to buid with only one gridView, and several Item Templates, 
OR should I buid a new user control from strach?

Comment: which language? Or am I being dense?

Comment: Asp.Net 3.5, c#. thanks.

Comment: I would expect the answer to this question to be equally valid in VB or C#. Also fixed title and tags.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd recommend building your own user control from scratch for this.  Even when used for its intended purpose (displaying table-based data), working with the GridView is like having a root canal.

In general, when it comes to non-standard UI elements (like what you're doing), you will probably end up spending much more time trying to hammer an existing control into the shape you need than you would just writing your own from the ground up.

Comment: Build a user control - or if this is not going to be used elsewhere, just build the separate sections directly on the page (UserControl is after all just a section of a page...)

Comment: How is working with Gridview like having a root canal?  I haven't had too many bad experiences with it.

Comment: @Martin: you mean you've had good experiences with root canal? You must love nitrous oxide.

Answer (score 1):

Do you need all the functionality of a gridview, or are you just rendering and paging data? If not, then perhaps the Gridview is not the appropriate control to build from.

Also, be sure to look into the new ListView and datapager controls.

http://www.west-wind.com/WebLog/posts/127340.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I'd have a close look at [ExtJS's Grid](http://extjs.com/products/extjs/). It's impressive looking and has a lot of features you need. The JS file generated may be a bit large though so maybe [build your own](http://extjs.com/products/extjs/build/) if you're putting this on the internets.